# what code is suitable to run both agents in one queue?

Tags: java, anylogic

I have implemented the suggestions from the comments on my post yesterday, namely by creating 2 different sources if they have different agents, so they have different images. but I'm confused, how do I get the two agents to enter into 1 queue and based on the priority due date enter into the grooving process? but in arrival i have created table start_date and due_ date

in queue i use code " -agent.due_date_wb.due_date_spc22_1.getTime(); ". Is that true?

if true. Why is there still an error in that section when I build it?

can you see the picture that I sent sir

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ghsf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUZTl.png)

I've tried with other code, but still error. is there any solution? and I have also created a bolt agent variable
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCaXg.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab4Uy.png)

Comment: your question has missing information... we see that the queue assumes a agent of type Bolt, but the sources do not generate agents of type Bolt... The problem really is that you are at a level that is way too beginner so you don't even know how to ask questions.... go take our courses at noorjax.teachable.com or do some other tutorials to learn the basics before you engage in any modeling activity

Comment: sir, bolt agent, I made this because previously there was an expert who suggested using block combine to enter the queue based on the time limit, then I did. so this bolt is a new agent whose contents contain the parameters that I named the two agents (weldbolt and SPC along with the parameters that I specified in the weldbolt and SPC agents, the pictures can be seen in the link in the post). but I'm confused when it's blocked in the queue, the code I'm trying to error by calling the due date for the two agents respectively. so I ask like this.

Comment: Well, before following this suggestion, there are 2 sources. but I'm confused about which type of agent to choose? whereas I can only choose 1 agent, but I have 2 agents who must enter the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have both sources "feed" into a queue without anything in between. Just "draw" the connectors into the queue.

This may still cause issues in the queue if you need some specifics from the agents moving through, but that is a much more advanced topic, tbh

Comment: then for the properties in the queuing section: just click "priority based" without having to use code?

Comment: if you only use the connector, does that mean you don't have to use a block combine, sir?

Comment: you do not need a combine block if you do not want to combine agents from your 2 sources. They can flow through a queue individually. Try it in an example model yourself :)

Comment: but in the queueu properties in the advanced section, namely agent type, you can only choose 1 agent type. it means I have to create a new agent that contains both agents (weldbolt and SPC) or what, sir? i am confused on that part

Comment: This is advanced AnyLogic stuff, tbh. You'd need to use inheritance to give both agent types the same characteristic. Else, look into type-casting. But both are likely a bit beyond your current skill level. Why not use 2 queue blocks in 2 flow charts? Or, if this is just about having a different image for agents, I would actually recommend to have just 1 agent type and show different images for a different parameter value (not sure who recommended you to have 2 agent types just to show different images, sounds weird)

Comment: because in the existing ones, sir, the two products go through 1 queue for the grooving process. and this is also a job shop flow, so the two products are produced in different lines. then, if the right is beyond my ability, what should I do? and how do you suggest i can use it? what if 1 agent can go through different paths, different images, different start_date_dates and different amounts?

Comment: Learn about inheritance for AnyLogic. See the help, example models, etc. But this is not something you will cobble together quickly (if this is for homework). For homework, consider just using 1 agent type in 1 flow and give them different characteristics (parameter p_Type or similar) and show different pictures based on that...)

Comment: OK, I'll read it first and in conclusion, your suggestion is for the case I'm having trouble with, namely 2 sources or 2 agents to enter 1 queue? or how about 1 agent?

Comment: I really don't understand inheritance. I've read and tried it but confused. is there any other solution sir? does this inheritance have to be population or can it be single? there are no "steps" to do inheritance? in the help it only says vehicles: lorry and truck, what does that mean? lorry and truck are created by new agents or parameters?

Comment: it is advanced Java so there is no easy way to get there. You can always model anything without inheritance, also in your case. It is just the best solution for the particular problem you described. But my tip: try to solve your task differently. Use the simple-most way... You can do it (and do use us as a helping hand)

Comment: I don't know how anymore, sir. what should i do to make the simulation run? I really hope there is another solution that can solve my problem. I'm also having a hard time finding solutions on other stackoverflows but haven't found them yet